# *Asher Bamayim* (אשר במים) in kashrus halacha

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, words, animals, fish

To find the kashrus status of an organism, we first need to correctly classify it as plant, animal, bird, or *asher bamayim**, as each group has its own distinct requirements. E.g., animals need to chew cud and have cloven hooves, while *asher bamayim* need (fins and) scales.

What is the halachic definition of *asher bamayim* (אשר במים)?

---

<sup>* This is how the Torah calls water-living creatures. Rabbinical writings use the word *dag* (דָג).</sup>

Comment: Should your list include "bug"? Should all of the terms be in Torah-Hebrew (or, better yet, in both Torah-Hebrew and English-in-quotes)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19404/discussion-between-nbz-and-isaac-moses).

Comment: Being completely water-bound has been suggested as a definition, however, both [dolphins](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Beluga-DolphinLand-Antalya-2006.jpg), and [amphibious fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibious_fish) would thereby be excluded.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50310/5323

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/what-defines-a-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%94

Comment: Maybe dolphins and amphibious fish _should_ be excluded.

Comment: I believe Hullin discusses the classification of a seal and concludes that you can tell where its from by testing where it runs when it is afraid.

Comment: Dag appears to be an animal that is completely water bound to include a whale or dolphin. Thus a dag does not have to breathe water. @NBZ

Comment: @sabbahillel Appears? Did you see my picture of a dolphin?

Comment: No where in the Parsha that discusses fish does it say the word Dag. 

> את זה תאכלו מכל אשר במים, כל אשר לו סנפיר וקשקשת במים בימים ובנחלים
> אותם תאכלו. וכל אשר אין לו סנפיר וקשקשת בימים ובנחלים מכל שרץ המים
> ומכל נפש החיה אשר במים , שקץ הם לכם. ושקץ יהיו לכם, מבשרם לא תאכלו ואת
> נבלתם תשקצו. כל אשר אין לו סנפיר וקשקשת במים, שקץ הוא לכם

This would seem to indicate that any water living creature requires fins and scales to be Kosher, and that would be the case even if it is not a fish.

Answer (score 6):

A preliminary answer: according to the Aruch Hashulchan ([Y.D. 83:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.83.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) the sea-creatures (i.e. fish) that are permitted by the Torah are only those that are fish-like, in that they have bones and proliferate. Additionally, he writes that sea-creatures which look like land animals - even if they have fins and scales - are not included in the kosher כל אשר יש לו סנפיר וקשקשת במים.

Simply speaking, the Torah really means to include everything living in the sea. This is implied by the Ramban [on Vaykira 11:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.10?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ramban_on_Leviticus.11.10.1&lang2=bi) who includes sea creatures with legs like those of land animals, and the Vilna Gaon (Keilim 10:1) that says that the Torah gives all sea-creatures have the same halakhic status, seemingly in all matters.

If צפרדעים are frogs, then my inclination would be to say that they too are sea-creatures despite being amphibious (based on [Shemos 7:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.7.28?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) but I have no source

Comment: +1, but can you maybe clarify the language a bit? The first paragraph seems to imply that jellyfish, squids, and crustaceans are not "asher bamayim", but the second seems to contradict.

Comment: @NBZ I think that they disagree (hence 'contradict'), but I don't really understand the Aruch Hashulchan