# *Of* (עוֹף) in kashrus halacha

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals, birds

To find the kashrus status of an organism, we first need to correctly classify it as plant, animal, *of*, or fish, as each group has its own distinct requirements. E.g., animals need to chew cud and have cloven hooves, while fish need (fins and) scales.

What is the halachic definition of a *of* (עוֹף)?

Comment: Penguins! Yum .

Comment: @DoubleAA That would be a *dag*, wouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe? It's highly unlikely penguins were on Moshe's list of not-kosher birds. ("Thou shalt not eat penguins." "Psst...this guy is _going_ 'penguins', if you know what I mean...")

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50304/5323

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/what-defines-a-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%94

Comment: E.g. Was the [moa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moa) a bird? It had no wings (not even vestigial one), and its feathers resembled fur more than plumage.

Answer (score 1):

Note that many translations have both a bat and an ostrich listed as "birds". As an example, Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan in *Living Torah* and the English translator in Rav Hirsch (his grandson Isaac Levy) use Bas Haya'ana as ostrich and ataleif as bat. These translations state that both an ostrich and a bat are halachically considered "of". Thus it appears that a bird is a "winged animal" whether or not it flies. A penguin would seem to be similar to an Ostrich in that it is a flightless winged animal.

Actually, if one wants to analyze a flipper and a wing, one could say that a fish "flies" through the water or a bird "swims" through the air. In both cases, they are propelled through the external medium by something very similar.

Comment: Why did you delete? Seems reasonable.

Comment: @msh210 Because I had two downvotes and did not want to spend more time on it. I will leave it undeleted until Sunday and see what happens.

Comment: Do penguins have wings or flippers? Are whales birds too?

Comment: @DoubleAA Penguins have the equivalent of wings and are not restricted to the water. Whales would have flippers but are completely restricted to the water so they are dagim.

Comment: @sabbahillel (...based on the rule you just made up out of thin air.) What is the difference between a wing and a flipper that you know which a penguin has?

Comment: @DoubleAA because the penguin is not completely water bound an appear (on the land) to be a flightless bird. It is thus not a dag

Comment: (1) Where are these translations coming from? (2) Why would those translations have bearing on the halachic definition of the "עוף"?

Comment: So, having no wings at all, a [Moa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moa) is not a bird? What about [flying fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_fish)'s fins?

Comment: @NBZ Since a flying fish is still a water animal, it would be a dag just as a "flying squirrel" (unlike a bat) is a land animal The fins of a "Flying" fish are still fins and not wings. A Moa had vestigial wings as shon in the wikipedia article that it is related to flying species.

Comment: "still a water animal" – Because you say so? "A Moa had vestigial wings" – Try re-reading Wikipedia: "The nine species of moa were the only wingless birds, **lacking even the vestigial wings** which all other ratites have."

Comment: I assume you would classify [flying dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draco_(genus)) as a land animal, since it is still a lizard? (sarcasm) Why wouldn't you classify a bat as a land animal, since it is still a mammal?

Comment: @NBZ because the torah does not classify in the same way as Linnaeous (spelling?)

Comment: I agree that the Torah doesn't (necessarily) classify like Linnaeus, but how DOES the Torah classify? You can't just make assumptions without a source, or a at least a hint. Yes, the Torah calls both bats and ostriches *of*, but since their "wings" are already anatomically radically different, that is not enough to rule fish fins and lizard ribs as not wings. despite their