# Are all fish in Tanach merely called "דג"?

Tags: names, halacha-theory, fish, parashat-shemini, yoreh-deah

A friend of mine told me that with the exception of the Leviasan, everything we might colloquially call "fish" nowadays are merely called "דג" (or "דגה" if its female) in Tanach. I asked several Rabbis and they couldn't think of any other species of fish named in Tanach. Is this true? If yes, why would that be?

I want to know because this friend was using this to explain why [Shach Y.D. 107:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4318) writes that a Treif fish mixed into Kosher fish is Min Bemino if you hold that Min Bemino goes by the name "משום דשם דג אחד הוא." Is that a valid explanation? (Note that Treif fish probably won't be getting mixed into your Leviyasan anytime soon.)

Comment: What about the תנין

Comment: @DoubleAA Rashi on Shemos 7:9 says that Tanin means snake.

Comment: Rashi to Gen 1:21 says it's a fish. But anyway maybe it's a water snake? Or some sort of marine slithery thing like an eel? Or maybe there are other opinions besides Rashi which are closer to peshat?

Comment: It seemingly must be a creature that can survive on land. It may be amphibious. Either way, it doesn't seem to be a type of fish.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50304/asher-bamayim-%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D-in-kashrus-halacha

Comment: I'm not sure you're right that דגה is female for fish...

Comment: We should also remember that the language of Tanakh is artificially kept to a small vocabulary so that we aren't left with words whose translations are lost. Given that we've been continuously been farmers until a little over a century ago, tzon may have been a safer word to use than whatever the Tanakh-era word was for halibut.

Answer (score 2):

Besides for perhaps the very first animal mentioned in Tanach, the תנינים (Genesis 1:21), overall, there do not appear to be any fish given other names in Tanach (see e.g. [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A0%22%D7%9A)).  Some commentators suggest בהמות (Job 40) refers to a quasi-aquatic creature, such as the hippopotamus.  Also, some of the שרצים may be aquatic or quasi-aquatic, such as the צב (Leviticus 11:29; see also Leviticus 11:10 "שרץ המים"; and צפרדע - Exodus 8 ).  Some also interpret the תחש (e.g. Exodus 25:5) as a seal or narwhal. Proverbs 30:15 also refers to the עלוקה, interpreted as a leech.

Comment: Also זה הים גדול ורחב ידים שם רמש ואין מספר חיות קטנות עם גדלות כו שם אניות יהלכון לויתן זה יצרת לשחק בו

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I think you're right. But, for what it's worth, the 19th century linguist Emmanuel Löw suggested that the last two words of Tehillim 74:14,

"אַתָּה רִצַּצְתָּ רָאשֵׁי לִוְיָתָן תִּתְּנֶנּוּ מַאֲכָל לְעָם לְצִיִּים"

should be read as the plural of a sea-creature called Amaletz. In modern Hebrew, this is the name for a type of shark.